# Laravel update database field according to timestamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

**Using Laravel 6.2**

I have a table in my database, which has (among others) three columns

- `status` (type : enum)
- `start` (type: timestamp)
- `end` (type : timestamp)

I want to automatically update `status` :

1. When `status` is `ready` AND the actual timestamp corresponds to `start`
   => it changes to `started` (I don't want to update the `status` if it is not `ready` !)
2. When `status` is `started` AND the actual timestamp corresponds to `end` => it changes to `ended`

I have been reading from the official doc about:
[Task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling), [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events) and [Queus](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues) but I don't know quite where to start.

The best trick I found was schedule a command that will run a database request every minute and check if it needs to update any field but I want to know what's the best way to do it.

Comment: I think, it depends on your requirements. If you need change the status in the correct second, then cron job (which run only every minute) is not enough. Then you should use scheduled jobs. But scheduled jobs means more work also. You need properly working queue, and also removing old jobs and creating new job when you edit start/end timestamp.

Comment: @Autista_z, it's not required to work on the exact second. So basically, I either have to schedule a job that runs every minute or manage through queuing jobs and removing them if needed ... ?

Comment: Yea, I know about this 2 options.